# Problem using HDI membership provider with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, custom-membershipprovider

I am trying to use HDI custom membership provider and after seting up with web.config when I run the applcation it gives me an error as shown below.

And I am unable to know where I am going wrong?Can anyone point me the right way?

```
Failed to map the path '/'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.
```

This is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HDIConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=HDIMembershipProvider;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="HDIMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="HDIMembershipProvider" type="HDI.AspNet.Membership.HDIMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="HDIConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <machineKey validationKey="34A0AF973A6817E4F7067DA1486E93AD5F7466B65D32405DB50766FDF335304F499C7B1943C084C7A67B1375D196CF02C8E84F297F7A0CA130C1D5722586749F" decryptionKey="48C8B6F952BC7C39DD91A2A17F17B08E113967DC5FF687FE6DFAF65F3248309C" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
   <system.net>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is caused by the MembershipProvider?

Comment: Can you post the error full stack trace? As this doesn't seem to be caused by the membership provider.

Comment: Yes as before I worked with one of my database and it worked fine.

Comment: @Frazell sorry I couldn't post the full error as here I am getting error as Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rectified the problem just by starting Visual Studio as Administrator.